# Is Outlast 2 a Prequel or a Sequel?

Tags: outlast

I've been searching around and I have found one answer which is "it's in the same universe" so that shows that it could either be a prequel or a sequel.

Comment: As far as the developers have said (that I've seen anyway), it is the same universe, but neither a prequel or a sequel. It's a completely different story with completely different characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To piggy back on what @Kaizerwolf has said in the comments above.  Outlast 2 is going to be an "Indirect Sequel" that will "take place in the same universe at Outlast, but it will feature different characters and a different setting" According to the [Outlast 2 Wikia](http://outlast.wikia.com/wiki/Outlast_2).

I'm sure more details will be released as the game continues to develop.  I hope this helps out :)

Comment: thanks man it makes more sense now and hopefully we do get more details i like to play games in chronological order you know.